# Работа с Реестром через C#

Tags: c#, реестр

Есть код

```
public RegClassSave(int sumDay, DateTime date)
    {
        try
        {
            int RegResult = SumResultDay;

            SumDay = sumDay;
            DateN = date;

            RegistryKey KnockOff = currentUserKey.CreateSubKey("KnockOff");

            KnockOff.SetValue("Amout", SumDay);
            KnockOff.SetValue("AmoutResult", SumResultDay);
            KnockOff.SetValue("Date", DateN);
            KnockOff.Close();

            string Amout = currentUserKey.OpenSubKey("KnockOff", true).GetValue("Amout").ToString();
            string AmoutResult = currentUserKey.OpenSubKey("KnockOff", true).GetValue("AmoutResult").ToString();
            string Date = currentUserKey.OpenSubKey("KnockOff", true).GetValue("Date").ToString();

            RegResult += Convert.ToInt32(Amout) + Convert.ToInt32(AmoutResult);       

            Console.WriteLine("Введённая сумма = {0} Результат = {1} Дата внесения = {2}", Amout, RegResult, Date);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ошибка {0}", e);
        }
    }       
}
```

В реестр всё добовляеться. Я не как не могу сделаь так что бы после запуска второй раз и ввода ещё одного числа, в реестор на место поля (AmoutResult) записывалось уже новое число (Amout + AmoutResult) тоесть сумма чисел.
Считывание тоже работает.

Вызов делаю так

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int EnterSum = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


            RegClassSave regClassSave = new RegClassSave(EnterSum, DateTime.Now);
    }
}
```

Не могу понять по чему не работает.

Comment: А где Вы считываете старое значение `AmoutResult` из реестра?

Comment: @default locale Извеняюсь я не тот код скинул. Сейчас правельный код.

Comment: Зря Вы описание класса убрали, теперь непонятно откуда `SumResultDay`, лучше верните его. Судя по всему, Вы больше нигде не считываете `AmoutResult` правда ведь?

Comment: @default locale `RegResult += Convert.ToInt32(Amout) + Convert.ToInt32(AmoutResult);` вот здесь считываю и добовляю значение в `int RegResult = SumResultDay;` и таким образом при следующем вызове значение присваеваеться вSumResultDay. Ну по крайне мере задумка такая.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Здесь считываю и добавляю значение в int RegResult = SumResultDay; и таким образом при следующем вызове значение присваивается вSumResultDay

C# так не работает. `RegResult` — локальная переменная. Она каждый раз создается заново и изменения ее значения ни на чем не отражаются, если этого отдельно не прописать.

Можно сохранять общую сумму в `SumResultDay` — это свойство класса и оно будет сохраняться пока есть объект, которому оно принадлежит. Для этого можно ему присваивать значение в конце метода:

```
SumResultDay = RegResult;
```

Либо вообще обойтись без `RegResult`:

```
SumResultDay = Convert.ToInt32(Amout) + Convert.ToInt32(AmoutResult);
```

Но тут возникнет другая проблема: Вы все делаете в конструкторе, а значит при каждом сохранении создается новый объект, с новыми свойствами и значение им присваивается по умолчанию (0).

Логичнее будет каждый раз вычитывать данные из реестра:

```
RegistryKey knockOff = currentUserKey.CreateSubKey("KnockOff");

//читаем значение из реестра
var value = knockOff.GetValue("AmoutResult");
int amountResult = Convert.ToInt32(value);
//прибавляем текущее значение
amountResult += sumDay;
...
//и лишь потом сохраняем сумму
knockOff.SetValue("AmoutResult", amountResult);
```

Тогда актуальное значение будет храниться в реестре и обновляться по необходимости. Вам понадобится также добавить проверку значения реестра на `null` чтобы при отсутствии значения в реестре записывать текущую сумму.

Еще, от конструктора ожидается что он будет выполнять только инициализацию класса, а не сложные манипуляции с реестром. Так что лучше было бы код перенести из конструктора в методы и свойства. Например, чтобы с классом можно было работать так:

```
RegClassSave regClassSave = new RegClassSave;
//свойство для хранения даты
regClassSave.DateN = DateTime.Now;
//метод, который работает с реестром и текущей суммой
regClassSave.Save(EnterSum);
//свойство для чтения общей суммы
Console.WriteLine(regClassSave.SumResultDay);
```

Comment: Спасибо за очень ёмкий ответ. Про конструктор вот оно! Огромное спосибо! Два дня возилься не мог понять почему результат не тот! Теперь вроде понял! Буду пробовать!

Comment: @j.Atisto Пожалуйста! Удачи!

Comment: Спасибо, всё получилось!!!